# Logging errors in SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, error-logging

I have a `ssis` project with 3 `ssis` packages, one is a parent package which calls the other 2 packages based on some condition. In the parent package I have a foreach loop container which will read multiple `.csv` files from a location and based on the file name one of the two child packages will be executed and the data is uploaded into the tables present in MS SQL Server 2008. Since multiple files are read, if any of the file generates an error in the the child packages, I have to log the details of error (like the filename, error message, row number etc) in a custom database table, delete all the records that got uploaded in the table and read the next file and the package should not stop for the files which are valid and doesn't generate any error when they are read.

Say if a file has 100 rows and there is a problem at row number 50, then we need to log the error details in a table, delete rows 1 to 49 which got uploaded in the database table and the package to start executing the next file.

How can I achieve this in SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set **TransactionOption**=**Required** on your foreach loop container and **TransactionOption**=**Supported** on the control flow items within it. This will allow for your transactions to be rolled back if any complications happen in your child packages. More information on 'TransactionOption' property can be found @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690.aspx

Custom logging can be performed within the child packages by redirecting the error output of your destination to your preferred error destination. However, this redirection logging only occurs on insertion errors. So if you wish to catch errors that occur anywhere in your child package, you will have to set up an 'OnError' event handler or utilize the built-in error logging for SSIS (SSIS -> Logging..)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the creation of two dataflows in your loop container. The main idea here is to have a set of three tables to better and more easily handle the error situations. In the same flow you do the following:

*1st dataflow*:
Should read .csv file and load data to a temp table. If the file is processed with errors you simply truncate the temp table. In addition, you should also configure the flat file source output to redirect the errors to an error log table.

*2nd dataflow*:
On the other hand, in case of processing error-free, you need to transfer the rows from temp into the destination table. So, here, the OLEDB datasource is "temp table" and the OLEDB destination is "final table".

Don´t forget to truncate the temp table in both cases, as the next file will need an empty table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down a bit.

I assume that you have a data flow that processes an individual file at a time. The data flow would read the input file via a source connection, transform it and then load the data into the destination. You would basically need to implement the Error Handler flow in your transformations by choosing "Redirect Row". Details on the Error Flow are available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/error-handling-in-data.

If you need to skip an entire file due to a bad format, you will need to implement a Precedence Constraint for failure on the file system task.

My suggestion would be to get a copy of the exam preparation book for exam 70-463 - it has great practice examples on exactly the kind of scenarios that you have run into.

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar with Excel files
We have an ErrorsFound variable which is reset each time a new file is read within the for each loop.
A script component validates each row of the data and sets the ErrorsFound variable to true if an error is found, and builds up a string containing any error details.
Then - based on the ErrorsFound variable -  either the data is imported or the error is recorded in a log table.

It gets a bit more tricky when the Excel files are filled in badly enough for the process not to be able to read them at all - for example when text is entered in a date, number or currency field. In this case we use the OnError Event Handler of the Data flow task to record an error in the log but won't know which row(s) caused the problem